# How can I find the API key in google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/mapview"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:apiKey="YOUR API KEY"
 />
```

This is the XML code for Google map view.is there anything need to add in `AndroidManiFest.xml`?

I can not understand.any one can help ?

Comment: you have to generate it using keytool, which would be found under JDK installation on your drive

Comment: @serzila10 refer this link for detail about API key https://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html.. and what is your exact question??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the exact path--

```
    keytool -list -keystore "C:\Users\XYZ\.android\debug.keystore"
```

Total path for cmd prompt to get the MD5 fingureprint for the GoogleMap API Key***************

```
    D:\eclipse\jre\bin>keytool -list -keystore "C:\Users\XYZ\.android\debug.keystore"
```

MD5 fingurePrint will look like this--

```
   3E:F4:D6:E6:93:4D:BB:B8:62:3A:D6:0F:E0:FC:4C:65
```

When u get the fingurePrint number afterthat to get the API Key use this link---

```
   http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-api-signup.html
```

Then u will get API key of your system and can get the Map easily....

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup). It will guide you completely on generating an API key and migrating from debug keystore to release keystore once you are on a stage to roll out your app on Google Play Store.

**Note: If you are using Android Studio, then generating SHA-1 is not a big deal.**

Follow these steps:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open Your Project
3. Click on Gradle (from Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)
4. Click on Refresh (click on Refresh from Gradle Bar, you will see List Gradle scripts of your Project)
5. Click on Your Project (your Project Name form List (root))
6. Click on Tasks
7. Click on android
8. Double Click on signingReport (you will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar)

Answer (score -2):

To generate your google api key you can do it with either by using debug debug.keystore or with you private keystore .

As part of process first you need to create account in google api console from here --> [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&reusekey=true).

Now you need to generate SHA1 of your debug.keystore or from your private keystore by following command for MAC OS .

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

For windows :

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

After this command you will get SHA1 like below example :

```
SHA1: BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:07:71:9B:62:90:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75
```

Now you just need to set this SHA1 in your google developer api console .

Please Visit this [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/)